# How to write the git change log for two particular builds in a file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wish to write the git change log for two particular builds in a file in Jenkins.

I have used " git change log " plugin it shows the difference between latest one and the previous one and follows;

Not for the particular two builds.

Eg:

input : build1, build10

Output should be the git change log between build1 and build10

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the GIT_COMMIT Environment variable from the two build you wanted and then do a git log between those commits.

Example: git log --pretty=oneline COMMIT_X COMMIT_Y

If you want the difference in the repo files itself you have to do git diff between those commits.

Example:git diff COMMIT_X COMMIT_Y